# How to use Entity Framework SqlQuery<> when the Entity type is known at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I am working on an `ASP.NET Web Forms` project. Due to the specifics of the project most of the data is in `XML` files, and when I return data from some view I have only a `string` value of the Entity type that I'm working with. Or to make it more clear, I return `json` where I have something like `{entity : "Clients"}` and that's the only way for me to know that I'm working with `Clients` at the moment.

So we still try to hang on to `Entity Framework 5` so in the `XML` files we store our DB queries, but the problem is that when I want to execute :

```
        using(var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var allRecords = db.Database.SqlQuery<???>("SELECT * FROM Clients");
```

I don't have the type as real type to give to the `SqlQuery` method. So the options that I think I can consider here are :

- Using classes to match the data - the most common answer when it comes to this problem but in my case the extensive use of `XML` files would be pointless.
- Using some sort of reflection to cast my string value to the actual Entity type since I have them in `POCOs` (I'm using `DataBase first` approach). I saw some pointers on how eventually this could be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method) but to be honest it's pretty complicated for me and I'm not even sure if this will work in that particular scenario, but if you think it's a good way to go please mention it.
- I was wondering if I can use `dynamic` somehow like so `SqlQuery<dynamic>` - it's returning correctly all the records from the database but I can't extract any data from that. I guess with dynamic I still have to cast the result at some point. Not sure, maybe someone knows a way?
- And last. We really want to use `Entity Framework` but this is just the starting phase of the project trying things out, seeing how things work together and I'm starting to think that maybe `Entity Framework` is just not the right tool in this situation. I got this brief answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16864592/how-to-use-entity-framework-when-entities-properties-are-only-known-at-runtime) and it really made me think about if I should put effort into twisting something when there's just a better approach doing it.

Comment: Do you have a backing model of any kind or is everything coming from the xml?

Comment: @Shoe I use `ADO NET Entity Data Model` to create my model from the SQL Database so I have `edmx` schema with `DbContext` and all my Entities created.

Comment: And what if you use the non generic overload: `dynamic allRecords = db.Database.SqlQuery(theCurrentType, "SELECT * FROM Clients")`?